# Стили в head cms open cart, которых нет в header.tpl

Tags: cms, opencart

На странице в браузере есть инлайновые стили, fontawesome, ... + modernizer.js:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в `/view/theme/default/template/common/header.tpl` (после стилей для ie7) ничего нет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос:** где в open cart можно найти эти стили? Может быть через админку как-то задаются?

Плюс modernizer подключается каким-то образом в шапке и генерируется в футере код:

```
          $(document).on('ready', function(){
                if (!Modernizr.csstransforms) {
                    $('.cut_rotated span').removeClass('rotated');
                    $('.cut_rotated span').addClass('horizontal');
                }

                if (!Modernizr.borderradius) {
                    if (window.PIE) {
                        $('.round').each(function() {
                            PIE.attach(this);
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
```

В каком-то же файле есть этот кусок кода? Уже, кажется, все файлы просмотрела и не найду.

Answer (score 3):

Тут вариантов несколько: в default теме в header.tpl есть такие строки:

```
<?php foreach ($styles as $style) { ?>
```

и

```
<?php foreach ($scripts as $script) { ?>
<script src="<?php echo $script; ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<?php } ?>
```

для подключения дополнительных скриптов и стилей, массив которых формируется в контроллере header.php:

```
$data['styles'] = $this->document->getStyles();
$data['scripts'] = $this->document->getScripts();
```

Но у Вас в коде я этих строк не вижу. Тогда, скорее всего, это дел рук модулей-модификаторов, чаще всего, они добавляют строки перед закрывающим тегом `</head>`
Список установленных OCMOD модификаторов можно посмотреть в админке в разделе "Менеджер дополнений". А сами изменения, которые вносят ocmod модификаторы, можно посмотреть в базе данных Вашего магазина в таблице oc_modification.

Comment: `<?php foreach ($styles as $style) { ?>` есть такое, но если я переношу его в footer все равно подключает в head или так и должно быть?

Comment: В футере этот код не сработает. В контроллере footer.php нет переменной `$styles` , должен вылезти notice или warning. Да и нельзя стили в футер переносить, а скрипты можно. Вообще этот код нужен чтобы при установке сторонних дополнений система могла подключать нужные им стили и скрипты. После внесения изменений в файлы шаблона надо обновлять кэш модификаторов, иначе результата не будет. Погуглите как работает встроенный в OpenCart механизм OCMOD или vQmod, если у Вас первая версия OpenCart.